# Using Zend_Http_Client to send json POST

Tags: php, json, post

I'm trying to send a json object as a POST command using the following:

```
    $uri = "http://amore-luce.com/product_create";
    $product =  $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($product);
    Mage::log(" Json={$json}", null,'product-updates.txt');

    // new HTTP request to some HTTP address
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://amore-luce.com/product_create');
    // set some parameters
    $client->setParameterPost('product', $json);
    // POST request
    $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
```

When I view the $json the data is  there and all looks good - however the POST is not sending the json data. I'm capturing it using a simple email form that should send me the response:

```
    <?php        
    $webhookContent = "";
    $ref = "";       
    $webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
    while (!feof($webhook)) {
        $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
    }
    fclose($webhook);

     $headers = array();
        foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
            if (substr($key, 0, 5) <> 'HTTP_') {
                continue;
            }
            $header = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))));
            $headers[$header] = $value;
        }

    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        $ref .= "$header: $value <br />\n";
    }

    $post = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $to = "address@my-email.com"; //the address the email is being sent to
    $subject = "This is the subject"; //the subject of the message
    $msg = "This is the message  -  Webhook content:  ".$webhookContent."    This is url:  ".$ref; //the message of the email

    mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From: PHP Scriptv2 <noreply@domain.com>'); //send the email.

    echo ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."<br>".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    ?>
```

This page works with other json POST requests I've sent to it.  I'm fairly new at sending POST requests so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try change :

```
$client->setParameterPost('product', $json);
```

to :

```
$client->setHeaders('Content-type','application/json');
$client->setParameterPost('product', $json);
```

or use:

```
$client->setRawData($json, 'application/json');
```

Comment: Using  $client->setRawData($json, 'application/json'); fails.  However using the two lines above works a treat.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So Update / Answer changing how I did it to these lines of code:

```
    $uri = "http://requestb.in/p6p4syp6";
    $product =  $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($product);
    Mage::log(" Json={$json}", null,'product-updates.txt');

    $client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri);
    $client->setRawData($json, null)->request('POST');
```

Changing the SetRawData($json, null) was the bit - using SetRawDate($json, 'application/json') caused it to fail.

Thanks Voodoo417 - I'll also try your suggestion and see if that lets me set the correct type